# How do I Automate the Task of Getting SPAN Text from a long list of URL's?

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation, browser-automation

I have a list of 15K URL's and I have to get the Current Title of the Product. Currently I can achieve this by running the following script in Browser Console

```
var mytitle = document.getElementById("productTitle").innerText;
console.log(mytitle)
```

The problem is to Automate the task and write the Product Title in a File (Excel/Text) instead of doing it manually. How would I achieve the result.

[Example Image for Product Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIJ5A.png)

Comment: Is there any automation or RPA product/tool you have tried. I'm a UiPath developer working in automation and sounds like UiPath could definitely solve this relatively simply. Another solution would be to use curl or wget then use some regex or parsing to extract the title.

Comment: I was able to grab the 'SPAN ProductTitle' innerText Attribute from "Get Attribute" using UiPath. Currently I have completed 95% of the Task. Thanks to you.
However, I still am to find the way to write the innerText into the Excel File - "Get Text" does not work as every Product Title is different - "Get Attribute" works like a charm but I still am unable to find a way to write it into the Excel.
Need more guidance...

Answer (score 0):

This is an image of the site which is on php and mysql. This products create by using mysql code, example: "SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'product_id' = 8".

Comment: This is an Image of Amazon, and I do not have access to Database, I have to do it while taking help from outside tools only.